# Using Java Stacks to evaluate a Valid Lisp Expression

Tags: java, lisp, operators, stack

For a project in, `Data Structures`, we are encouraged to evaluate a `Lisp Expression` using `Java API Stacks`.

The `Lisp expressions` have the four basic operators: `+, -, *, / .`
Valid tokens in the expression are `'(', ')'`, and the operators.

An example `Lisp expression`:  `( +   (-6) (+ 3 2 1) (/ 10 5) (* 2 3 4))` which equals `26`.

---

How can I compute the tokens of the `Lisp`, and then push them back into the `stack`?

Comment: To be honest, nothing really. That's only, because I'm unsure on what to do. I'm a beginner Java programmer and don't have much of a deep understanding of Java (although I'm reading Thinking In Java by Bruce Eckel to understand it more).

Comment: I'm supposed to pop the operands from one stack to another until I find an operator, then I apply the operator to the operands. After which I push back the result to the original stack.      -------> I'm unsure on how to calculate the operands and then push back the result.

Comment: I wont post code, just pictures then http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs124/javanotes3/c11/expressionTree.gif

Comment: I should have clarified in the beginning of my question that I do NOT want someone to post the code for me so I can copy and paste. I want to learn this stuff, so I can rely on myself and understand the concepts. Appreciate the picture @RamonBoza

Comment: happy to see you want to learn the correct way, use trees as in the picture ;)

Comment: Information is out there, just needed to look for it :/ thanks for the help Ramon.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105519/lisp-expression-evaluator-in-java-using-only-one-stack

Comment: @TheDude If you found information that answers this question, you should probably _delete_ this question or flag it and say that it's a duplicate of that other one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the recipe (yes, you have to *know* Java, no other way around it)

- Tokenize your input: you will have the following tokens

  - S-EXPR-START (every time you encounter '(')
  - S-EXPR-END (every time you encounter ')')
  - NUMBER (value being the value of the number parsed)
  - OPERATION (value being the operation code: +-*/ etc)
- Build a syntax tree: every time you start an s-expression (opening bracket) it is a new tree node, it's value being the function and children being the operands.
- Evaluate your tree in the bottom-up approach by replacing the node/children with the result of this node.
  ...
- PROFIT!